# Using edited List in one command at another command

Tags: c#, discord.net

I've crated a discord Bot command, which adds user message to List, however when I try to use the items added to list in another command I loose the changes in the list. I wanna add a for loop later on, so it will print the whole list, added just the index zero for now.[image of bot messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdkdN.png)
My current code is:

```
 [Command("add")]
        public async Task Pridat([Remainder] string zprava)
        {
            sracka = zprava;
            {
                AnotherList.Add(zprava);
                await ReplyAsync("hlaska " + zprava + " byla pridana");
                await ReplyAsync(AnotherList[0]);
                return;
            }

        }
        [Command("shw")]
        async Task Zobrazit()
        {  
            Console.WriteLine(AnotherList[0]);
            await ReplyAsync(AnotherList[0]);
            await ReplyAsync("Showing to dev");
        }
```

Comment: all this async business is almost certainly the culprit. Try to keep as much of your code synchronous as possible. I bet you can do what you are trying to do with a single `await`

Comment: Can I ask what do you mean? I don't thinky my bot will do what I want him to do without Async and await...

Answer (score -1):

You can add locks to you list so that you cannot read it while you are writing to it in Pridat

Comment: I always use the first command and then the other one. When I use the second one, first one should be finished already